# MySQL query to get last 12 months data grouped by month including zero counts

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by

I have table `orders (order_id, order_processed_date)`. I want the count of orders per month for last 12 months. If any month has 0 orders, then it should print 0.

Something like this:

```
Total Orders | Month
-----------------------
2            | OCT 2018
3            | SEP 2018
0            | AUG 2018
0            | JUL 2018
1            | JUN 2018
0            | MAY 2018
0            | APR 2018
0            | MAR 2018
5            | FEB 2018
5            | JAN 2018
0            | DEC 2017
0            | NOV 2017
```

I already searched in this website and get some queries but did not find exact solution for this. I get result using below query but it does not have year:

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(month = 'Jan', total, 0)) AS 'Jan',
SUM(IF(month = 'Feb', total, 0)) AS 'Feb',
SUM(IF(month = 'Mar', total, 0)) AS 'Mar',
SUM(IF(month = 'Apr', total, 0)) AS 'Apr',
SUM(IF(month = 'May', total, 0)) AS 'May',
SUM(IF(month = 'Jun', total, 0)) AS 'Jun',
SUM(IF(month = 'Jul', total, 0)) AS 'Jul',
SUM(IF(month = 'Aug', total, 0)) AS 'Aug',
SUM(IF(month = 'Sep', total, 0)) AS 'Sep',
SUM(IF(month = 'Oct', total, 0)) AS 'Oct',
SUM(IF(month = 'Nov', total, 0)) AS 'Nov',
SUM(IF(month = 'Dec', total, 0)) AS 'Dec'
FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_processed_date, '%b') AS month, 
COUNT(order_id) as total
FROM orders
WHERE order_processed_date <= NOW() and order_processed_date >= 
Date_add(Now(),interval - 12 month)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_processed_date, '%m-%Y')) as sub
```

Can please someone help me to give me result as I required.

Comment: You need another master table to store all the months, and take that as your first table in the left join.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya What about years ? only just need to store months only ?

Comment: Don't you need data only for last 12 months ? You can use `YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())` to get current year and subtract it by 1 to get previous year. This will be enough to cover 12 months

Comment: You can also emulate Month table using `select 'jan' union select 'feb' union 'mar' ...`

Comment: Can you give me example query or update in above query if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query builds a list of 1st day of month for previous 12 months. For example on `Oct 19 2018` the list will contain dates from `Oct 01 2018` to `Nov 01 2017`. Left join does the rest:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(orders.primary_key)
FROM (
    SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS date UNION ALL
    SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 3 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 4 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 5 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 6 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 7 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 8 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 9 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 10 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 11 MONTH UNION ALL
    SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
) AS dates
LEFT JOIN orders ON order_processed_date >= date AND order_processed_date < date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Perfect! got required data! Thanks.